# How to use FuncAnimation to display one scatter marker per frame

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, scatter-plot, matplotlib-animation

I am trying to use the `FuncAnimation` of Matplotlib to animate the display of one dot per frame of animation.

```
# modules
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as py
from matplotlib import animation

py.close('all') # close all previous plots

# create a random line to plot
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------

x = np.random.rand(40)
y = np.random.rand(40)

py.figure(1)
py.scatter(x, y, s=60)
py.axis([0, 1, 0, 1])
py.show()

# animation of a scatter plot using x, y from above
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------

fig = py.figure(2)
ax = py.axes(xlim=(0, 1), ylim=(0, 1))
scat = ax.scatter([], [], s=60)

def init():
    scat.set_offsets([])
    return scat,

def animate(i):
    scat.set_offsets([x[:i], y[:i]])
    return scat,

anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, init_func=init, frames=len(x)+1, 
                               interval=200, blit=False, repeat=False)
```

Unfortunately, the final animated plot is not the same as original plot. The animated plot also flashes several dots during each frame of animation. Any suggestions on how to correctly animate a scatter plot using the `animation` package?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The only problem with your example is how you fill the new coordinates in the `animate` function. `set_offsets` expects a `Nx2` ndarray and you provide a tuple of two 1d arrays.

So just use this:

```
def animate(i):
    data = np.hstack((x[:i,np.newaxis], y[:i, np.newaxis]))
    scat.set_offsets(data)
    return scat,
```

And to save the animation you might want to call:

```
anim.save('animation.mp4')
```

Comment: That works great. Thank you for the help. I didn't realize the requirements of the `set_offsets` function.

Comment: My `x` and `y` values were a Pythonic list of numbers, thus `scat.set_offsets(np.c_[x, y])` worked for me.

Answer (score 6):

Disclaimer, I wrote a library to try and make this easy but using `ArtistAnimation`, called [celluloid](https://github.com/jwkvam/celluloid/). You basically write your visualization code as normal and simply take pictures after each frame is drawn. Here's a complete example:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Agg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from celluloid import Camera

fig = plt.figure()
camera = Camera(fig)

dots = 40
X, Y = np.random.rand(2, dots)
plt.xlim(X.min(), X.max())
plt.ylim(Y.min(), Y.max())
for x, y in zip(X, Y):
    plt.scatter(x, y)
    camera.snap()
anim = camera.animate(blit=True)
anim.save('dots.gif', writer='imagemagick')
```

[image]

Comment: Except that *not* using this library would save you three lines of code. So it seems of rather limited scope.

Comment: I'm not sure how you counted 3 lines, but I don't disagree with you. I wrote the library because I would spend at least an hour each time I would try to use `FuncAnimation`. For me it was more about saving time than lines of code :)

Comment: Sure just be aware that ArtistAnimation is pretty costly. A 2 minutes animation at 20 fps creates 2400 artists in memory, quite a lot, compared to a single artist needed for FuncAnimation. It's ok if you are aware of the implications, but maybe a new user would benefit more from understanding the differences between Func- and ArtistAnimation and how to use them, instead of using a blackbox tool that might cause trouble later on. I'm saying that also with respect to e.g. `drawnow`, which is meant to simplify things, yet causes problems for almost anyone not understanding what it does.

Comment: I agree with your points. I figured that it used more memory but I wasn't sure how to quantify it. I need to add in more disclaimers about those sorts of things. I need to think more about the beginner to advanced transition. This package probably shouldn't be used by someone looking to advance past a beginner user of matplotlib's animation api.

Comment: Holy crap this is incredible. It works with seaborn plots too. Thanks so much. Glad I found this post.