# Issues with FuncAnimation in Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a set of scatter data that I am trying to animate with FuncAnimation but am not getting any output. I don't use matplotlib often and have never tried to animate anything before except in matlab.

That being said, I have dataframes with x,y data but cannot get the plot to work.
The cv,of,ol,nf,nl_data are dataframes with 'ewm_x' and 'ewm_y' being the x,y axis values.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
sc = ax.scatter([],[])
def update(frame):
    x_pos = [cv_data['ewm_x'].loc[frame], of_data['ewm_x'].loc[frame], ol_data['ewm_x'].loc[frame], nf_data['ewm_x'].loc[frame], nl_data['ewm_x'].loc[frame]]
    y_pos = [cv_data['ewm_y'].loc[frame], of_data['ewm_y'].loc[frame], ol_data['ewm_y'].loc[frame], nf_data['ewm_y'].loc[frame], nl_data['ewm_y'].loc[frame]]
    sc.set_offsets(np.hstack((x_pos, y_pos)))
    return sc
animation = FuncAnimation(fig, update, frames=cv_data.index.values, interval=20)
plt.show()
```

This is based off of this earlier question [scatter example 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26892392/matplotlib-funcanimation-for-scatter-plot)

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean when you say "cannot get the plot to work"? Here are a few things to change. Please clarify your question if this doesn't solve the problem.

#### Possible Solution

Create an `init_func` to call as a parameter when you run `FuncAnimation`. Note the comma in the return statement.

```
def init():
    sc.set_offsets([])
    return sc,
```

Change your return statement in `update(frame)` to include a comma.

```
return sc,
```

Change your naming/imports when you call the animation function.

```
import matplotlib.animation as animation

  *
  *
  *

anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig,update,init_func=init,frames=cv_data.index.values,interval=20,repeat = False,blit = True)
```

**Note:**
If this doesn't solve your issue, you may need to adjust which widget you use by including the line `%matplotlib ___` filled in with the widget you would like to use.

Comment: Cannot get the plot to work means no output on a graph. My note book says it was completed but the graph when plt.show() is called is blank. No animation, no points plotted of any kind. But also no error warning explaining what I could do to make it work

Comment: Are you using jupyter notebook? If so, put `%matplotlib notebook` at the very top of the kernel. You may have to restart the kernel before running it with the new line added.

Comment: I am but vscodium warns widget works best

Comment: Did you try `%matplotlib widget` then? What happened?

Comment: Yes but still no output to graph. Shows empty  inline plot only

Comment: Try saving your animation as an mp4. This will tell you if the animation part is actually working. If the video is saved correctly, then try opening a new notebook and copy all of your code into it with widget enabled. DO NOT RUN IT WITH inline. `anim.save('fileName.mp4', writer = 'ffmpeg', fps = 30)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252220/discussion-between-evan-and-trent).